# Fish shell: how to disable "git status" in prompt?

Tags: fish

I love Fish shows me "git status" in the prompt. However, it doesn't work well for really large git repos because it's very slow. How can I disable this feature based on the directory's name? Thanks!

Comment: `funced fish_prompt` then test it, then `funcsave fish_prompt`

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did. You need to replace those `<REPO>`

```
function fish_prompt
  set last_status $status

  set_color $fish_color_cwd
  printf '%s ' (prompt_pwd)
  set_color normal

  set BIG_REPOS <REPO1> <REPO2> <REPO3>
  if not contains (basename $PWD) $BIG_REPOS
    printf '%s ' (__fish_git_prompt)
  end

  set_color normal
end
```